# Execute script on page load in static FBML

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-fbml, staticfbml

How can I execute script on page load inside a FBML Static page?

What I want to do is make an ajax call to my application when the page loads and display some data.

I tried following script but it doesn't work. I don't get any message neither Success nor Error

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
 var ajax = new Ajax(); 
 ajax.responseType = Ajax.JSON;
 ajax.ondone = function(data) {          
  new Dialog().showMessage("Success", "Got Response");
 }

  ajax.onerror = function(data) {          
   new Dialog().showMessage("Error", "Failure");
  }

  ajax.requireLogin = false;
  ajax.post('http://www.xyz.com/abc');

 //--></script>
```

If I make it a function and call it through on click it works, and I get a success message

```
<a href="#" onclick="on_load(); return false;">Click</a>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function on_load() {
 var ajax = new Ajax(); 
 ajax.responseType = Ajax.JSON;
 ajax.ondone = function(data) {          
  new Dialog().showMessage("Success", "Got Response");
 }

  ajax.onerror = function(data) {          
   new Dialog().showMessage("Error", "Failure");
  }

  ajax.requireLogin = false;
  ajax.post('http://www.xyz.com/abc');
 }

 //--></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use FBJS (facebook version of JS). You can find documentation about ajax call [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/fbjs#ajax)

it will be something like

```
<script><!--

      var ajax = new Ajax();
      ajax.ondone = function(data) {
        //do something
      }
      ajax.post('http://example.com/testajax.php');    

   //-->
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

try to add next lines just to be sure that this is not a server error and a response type.

```
req.responseType=Ajax.FBML;    
ajax.onerror=function(data){
    alert("Something went wrong. Please, try again.");
}
```

> **ResponseType** can be one of Ajax.RAW, Ajax.JSON, or Ajax.FBML.

Are you using FireBug? Do you see a call to the server or any JS error?

**UPDATE**

if the problem is to run it on page upload event. You should put the script in the end of your page. Something like described [here](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=5117).

Comment: what exactly is not working? do you see any js errors in the console? do you try to put some alerts to see if you script part run in moment you want?

Comment: I have added the script that I used. and when I keep the above script in function and call on click it works

Comment: I have updated the question with more scripts I tried but no luck, even the firebug doesn't show any post being made to the server but it does show in case of onclick function.

Comment: Still doesn't work ... I guess the solution works for facebook app but not in Static fbml pages. I badly want this to work though :(

Comment: any ways thanks for the help will give a vote if it helps someone else